# Can you transitition from a semantic symbol back to a syntax tree node using Roslyn?

Tags: .net, roslyn

If I have a semantic symbol lets say a parameter coming in to a method, Can I some how go back to the syntax node of this symbol?

In the below code lets say I have a handle on the "param" Identifier in the syntax tree from the `param = "TEST"`, I swap over to the semantic model to determine the OriginalDefinition of param which takes me to the `string param` in the method declaration.  I now want to swap back to the syntax tree and goto the original definition node.

I was able to do this with what I would consider a hack `var token = tree.Root.FindToken(origNode.Locations[0].SourceSpan.Start).Parent;`

Is there a better way to do this?  Perhaps something similar to the `GetSemanticInfo()` but for the Syntax tree?

```
private void DoSomething(string param)
{
  param = "TEST";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't anything better in the current CTP, but this is feedback that we have heard, and we have a plan to address it in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  Ugh :(